# JavaEE 6 AsyncContext behavior after timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous

What is the exact behavior of AsyncContext after it times out? Does it still run and does it return response using getResponse()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Java Servlet 3.0** Maintenance Release on page 34 reads:

> A call to this method - `ServletRequest.startAsync(ServletRequest req,
>   ServletResponse res)` - ensures that the response isn't committed when
>   the application exits out of the service method. It is committed when
>   AsyncContext.complete is called on the returned AsyncContext or the
>   AsyncContext times out and there are no listeners associated to handle
>   the time out. The timer for async time outs will not start until the
>   request and it’s associated response have returned from the container.
>   The AsyncContext could be used to write to the response from the async
>   thread. It can also be used to just notify that the response is not
>   closed and committed.

From [the javadoc of the javax.servlet.AsyncContext interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html):

> In the event that an asynchronous operation has timed out, the
>   container must run through these steps:
>
> 1. Invoke, at their onTimeout method, all AsyncListener instances registered with the ServletRequest on which the asynchronous operation
>      was initiated.
> 2. If none of the listeners called complete() or any of the dispatch() methods, perform an error dispatch with a status code equal
>      to HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.
> 3. If no matching error page was found, or the error page did not call complete() or any of the dispatch() methods, call complete()."

The last line above is of most importance - there'll be a call to `AsyncContext.complete()`. [The javadoc says](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#complete%28%29):

> Completes the asynchronous operation that was started on the request
>   that was used to initialze this AsyncContext, closing the response
>   that was used to initialize this AsyncContext.

With `AsyncContext` closed, calls to most of its methods will throw `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @xwinus if you like the response, approve it.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski : +1. I think you have also indirectly answered the posters other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228031/java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-suspended-when-asynccontextcomplete) !